# Cannot remove liquidity ETH

Tags: uniswap, liquidity-provider, scam

I made and deployed below CA 'nah'

https://etherscan.io/token/0x4cffb2ff47d662be8d0919f97e8c08436b2afa26

I added liquidity and renounced, but forgot to use the Enable Trading function.

Now I cannot remove liquidity. Is there any way for me to go around this and be able to remove liquidity?

Answer (score 0):

Afraid no, removing liquidity from a Uniswap v2 pair calls the `transfer` function of both tokens, and the `nah`'s transfer function implementation has this code:

```
function _transfer(
    address from,
    address to,
    uint256 amount
) private {
    // ...
    if (from != owner() && to != owner()) {
        //Trade start check
        if (!tradingOpen) {
            require(from == owner(), "TOKEN: This account cannot send tokens until trading is enabled");
        }
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

Clearly, if `tradingOpen` is false, then one of `from` and `to` must be the `owner` address, which you have set to zero. Unless you have some backdoors in the contract, it's not possible to remove liquidity now.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. What I don't get, how is it possible to ADD liquidity but not REMOVE liquidity. Seems weird to me as both include moving the tokens around. Are you sure it's not possible?

Comment: @Rob Can you add liquidity now, at the current state?

Comment: no because i dont have any tokens anymore. The contract is here: https://etherscan.io/token/0x4cffb2ff47d662be8d0919f97e8c08436b2afa26. Do you see any backdoor?

Comment: Sorry, I have limited time to investigate this in depth. I would not have much hope TBH. Best to treat it as a learning experience.

Comment: @kfx why not call setTrading(true) ? don't want anyone else to be able to trade?

Comment: @user253751 because it's marked as `onlyOwner`, and they have renounced ownership.